# Spectral Class Breakdown

Tags: star, spectral-type

Where can I get a more detailed breakdown of Spectral Classes.  Wikipedia only has it at Letter level rather than sublevel.

For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification has B ranging from 10,000 - 30,000K.  B0 is different to a B9, what would be the temperature range for a B0 or a B9 but not limiting to B but for all letters?

I'm not just looking at Temperature, I'm after Mass, Radius, Luminosity, Hydrogen Lines etc.

The closest that I've come is https://sites.uni.edu/morgans/astro/course/Notes/section2/spectraltemps.html  but it doesn't mention types II or IV and doesn't have Radius or Mass.

Comment: Spectral type is connected with position in the HR diagram, there is no direct or one-to-one mapping with mass, except perhaps approximately on the main sequence, and even then it would be age and composition dependent.

Comment: Eric Mamajek has a [nice table for the main sequence](http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~emamajek/EEM_dwarf_UBVIJHK_colors_Teff.txt) (luminosity class V), but other luminosity classes have much less well-defined relationships. (And even the main sequence will have dependences on things like metallicity that aren't captured in the table).